# How to group UITableView data by month in Swift(iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm making an `iOS` sleep tracker app which has two `CoreData` attributes:

`sleepStartTime and sleepEndTime` which are of type `Date()`

My Sleep History tab currently looks like this:

[image: sleep history tab screenshot]

How do I organize the data by month and year and title the section (ex. November 2018) accordingly in `Swift`.

UPDATE:

Here is my current code -

```
var sleepHistory: [NSManagedObject]?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(false)

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "SleepEntryDetail")
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sleepStart", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    do {
        sleepHistory = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch data. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}



// MARK: - Table view data source


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return sleepHistory?.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt  indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SleepHistoryCell", for: indexPath)


let sleepDetail = sleepHistory![indexPath.row]

let sleepDuration = (sleepDetail.value(forKeyPath: "sleepEnd") as! Date).timeIntervalSince(sleepDetail.value(forKeyPath: "sleepStart") as! Date)

cell.textLabel?.text = "\(dateFormatter(date: (sleepDetail.value(forKeyPath: "sleepStart") as! Date)))"
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Duration: \(timeString(time: sleepDuration))"

return cell
}

func dateFormatter(date: Date) -> String {
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy '-' h:mm a"
 //http://nsdateformatter.com useful dataformatter resource
return dateFormatter.string(from:date)
}

func timeString(time: TimeInterval) -> String {
let hours = Int(time)/3600
let minutes = Int(time)/60 % 60
let seconds = Int(time) % 60
return String(format: "%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your code?

Comment: @Losiowaty I'm trying to implement the following concept https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009939-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2, but I don't know how to do it in Swift. My code as of now just fetches all the data and displays them in the table without any grouping.

Comment: The same way they did it in Objective-C. As far as official APIs/SDKs go, you can rewrite most of code samples 1:1.  I realise that reading Obj-C code may be hard if you are not familiar with it, but I highly encourage you to practice it, since there are a lot of code samples out there that are still valid, and being able to read and undestand them is really worthwhile. Check out the docs for the objects/methods being used in the sample, see how their counterpart in Swift is called (there might be minor differences in method names, due to naming conventions) and hack away.

Comment: Can you please print the data and show the format

Comment: @Losiowaty thank you, will try doing that, I have also added my current code to the post

Comment: @AbhinavJha I have added my current code to the question, the data is in Date format, and I use the DateFormatter() to convert it to String.

Answer (score 0):

If you want group data maybe you can try this

```
let groupByDate = Dictionary(grouping: data, by: { (element) -> String in
            return data.date
        }
```

Comment: I want to group them in sections in UITableView according to month. I don't think this code lets me do that.

Comment: @Sarvesh did u find the solution?